# Is it possible to dynamically refresh journalctl with less?

Tags: less, systemd-journald, journalctl

I'm using `less` to view my `journalctl` logs because it's more convenient. It doesn't clutter the console window with logs after you exit less and you can scroll using your mouse wheel.

```
journalctl --unit xyz | less +G
```

But it's very annoying that I cannot refresh the logs. Is there a way to do that with `less`? Using `Shift` + `F` doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But it's very annoying that I cannot refresh the logs. Is there a way to do that with `less`? Using `Shift` + `F` doesn't work.

You might be looking for `journalctl`'s, `--follow`/`-f`. That cancels the use of a pager by `journalctl`, so I guess you need to add it.

```
journalctl -fu xyz | less
```

Then `less`'s <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> works to see new entries that are added while you're viewing in `less`.

If you want to scroll up in `less` while `less` is waiting for new input (because you hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or simply scrolled to the bottom), then make sure to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> rather than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to interrupt its waiting for new entries. If you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, that's going to kill `journalctl` so you wouldn't be able to get new entries afterwards.

Here's an example video. I hope this clarifies:

[image]

[For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, you need to update to `less` version 633, released last May.](https://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/news.633.html)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. When I run `journalctl -fu xyz | less` the logs are updated live, but I cannot navigate using the arrow keys or scroll wheel.

Comment: @fire84392 Try pressing the F key, that's Shift+F for capital F, when hitting the bottom of the log. That should tell `less` to continue reading beyond the last recorded output. This won't be as seamless as the normal behavior of `journalctl -f` continuously showing new message as they arrive, but it's the best that `less` can do if you want to combine both.

Comment: Which steps do I have to follow? I run `journalctl --unit xyz | less` (without `--follow`), go to the bottom with `G` and press `Shift+F`? It doesn't work. It says `Waiting for data... (interrupt to abort)` but it doesn't update the logs. Also I cannot navigate anomore.

Comment: If I run `journalctl -fu xyz | less` like @JoL said, the logs get updated live. I don't have to press `Shift+F` and I cannot press `Shift+F`. It doesn't let me navigate or enter any commands. At the bottom of the console there's a blank line with a blinking caret. Usually there's a `:` and I can enter commands there.

Comment: Press Control-X to interrupt and now you can scroll up and down. When ready to see new output, scroll to the bottom and press Shift-F to continue following. After that, you will need to interrupt again if you want to scroll up.

Comment: `Ctrl+X` does nothing but `Ctrl+C` works. Updating has stopped and I can navigate now. I can press `Shift+F` and it says `Waiting for data... (interrupt to abort)`. But it doesn't update anymore.

Comment: @fire84392 "but it doesn't update anymore" -- That's why I said to use `Ctrl-x`. I put a video. I hope that clarifies.

Comment: @fire84392 If `Ctrl-x` doesn't work. It may be that your `less` is too old to support that.

Comment: @fire84392 "Usually there's a :" -- The `:` doesn't appear until the height of the terminal's been filled, because it doesn't make sense to scroll when everything is still visible on a single page. When you use `journalctl --follow` it doesn't show the whole history, just the last few entries. You can use `journalctl`'s `-n` to show more lines from the start.

Comment: @JoL My `less` is version 487. I guess that explains why nothing works. Thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: I just did a test with `less` version 530 from 2018 and it did not work. However, I can confirm that it works in version 633 from mid-2023. Installing an out-of-distro copy of `less` should be pretty easy as all you'll need to do after `make` is drop the `less` binary itself into `/usr/local/bin/` or similar otherwise, you just have to choose between using a pager or following.

Comment: @JoL "Usually there's a `:`" You're right. It appears when new lines get added to the log. But when I scroll to the bottom, it will disappear and I cannot go back up. Now the console window will follow when new lines appear in the log. Only if I spam many lines to the log, it gets detached from the bottom and the `:` appears. When I scroll to the bottom it's stuck again.

Comment: @penguin I will try updating less but the server doesn't belong to me and I don't even know how to do that on the command line. I will try to figure it out.

Comment: @fire84392 You don't need to install `less` system-wide if you don't want to interfere with someone else's server. I assume you have your own user account on it. Install it under your normal user's home directory, probably using either `$HOME/bin` or `$HOME/.local/bin` as the path. Create the folder if it doesn't exist and make sure it gets added to the beginning of your `$PATH` when logged in by updating your `~/.profile` or whatever is appropriate for your shell of choice. You just need to compile it on this system by running `make`, but don't need to run `make install`.

Comment: Just copy the compiled binary to the bin folder in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 8):

[`journalctl`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/journalctl.1.html#ENVIRONMENT) calls `less` anyway (on a typical system). It might be calling `less` with different [options](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html#OPTIONS) from what you'd like, but you can customize that through the `SYSTEMD_LESS` environment variable. The default is `FRSXMK`. You can set it to something like

```
export SYSTEMD_LESS='-M -R -S +G'
```

Comment: I find that I need `SYSTEMD_LESS=RMS+G` instead.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, right, `+command` has to go after options.

Comment: But how can I refresh the logs while viewing?

Comment: @fire84392 watch might help, i.e. re-execute peiorically.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd what do you mean with watch? I can re-execute the command of course (exit and run the command again).

Comment: @fire84392 Read the watch manpage.